# Count number of times a date changed per member

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL dataset where a member record may have been updated several times in one day.  The date_changed field will reflect each update.  I need to find how many times a record has been changed in a day.  I was playing around with a row_num() function, but I can't seem to get just the max times changed.  The Times Changed field shows what I need, and Ti shows what I've been able to get with row_num():

```
    MemberId    Date_Changed                 Times Changed     Ti
     1           2015-06-22 12:58:17             3              1
     1           2015-06-22 12:59:01             3              2
     1           2015-06-22 11:00:03             3              3
     6           2015-05-24 10:00:00             2              1
     6           2015-05-24 11:00:000            2              2
```

Thanks!

Comment: Edit your question and show data used to generate these results.

Comment: Is that your expected Result

Answer (score 1):

Based on your sample data, you seem to want the number of rows per member id on each date.  So, I think this is what you want:

```
select t.*,
       count(*) over (partition by memberid, cast(date_changed as date)) as TimesChanged
from t;
```

I speculate that you are using `row_number()` instead of `count(*)`.  SQL Server has no `row_num()` function (no database does, as far as I know).

Comment: Yes, I meant I was using row_number().  Changing to count(*) is giving me the same result as row_number(): 1, 2, 3 instead of 3, 3, 3.  I'm updating the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need code to get that expected Result

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Temp
;With cte( MemberId,Date_Changed)
AS
(
SELECT 1,'2015-06-22 12:58:17'  Union all      
SELECT 1,'2015-06-22 12:59:01'  Union all      
SELECT 1,'2015-06-22 11:00:03'  Union all      
SELECT 6,'2015-05-24 10:00:00'  Union all      
SELECT 6,'2015-05-24 11:00:000'     
)
SELECT * INTO #Temp FROm cte

SELECT MemberId,
      Date_Changed,
      Max(Date_ChangedCnt)Over(Partition by MemberId Order by MemberId) AS 'Times Changed', 
      Date_ChangedCnt AS Ti From
(
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER()Over(Partition By MemberId Order by Date_Changed) AS Date_ChangedCnt FROM #Temp
)Dt
```

Result

```
  MemberId         Date_Changed                 Times Changed     Ti
     1           2015-06-22 12:58:17             3              1
     1           2015-06-22 12:59:01             3              2
     1           2015-06-22 11:00:03             3              3
     6           2015-05-24 10:00:00             2              1
     6           2015-05-24 11:00:000            2              2
```